# I want to make a database where an ID can have multiple records

Tags: mysql, php, phpmyadmin

I am currently making an inmate information system in which the admin can insert multiple visitations records for a certain prisoner

This what my prisoner table looks like
[image: prisoner table]

Visitations table:
[image: visitations table]

I want it to be like this

[image: expected db]

I found out that it has something to do with my database but I'm struggling how to fix it. What should I do or change?

Also, This is my query for inserting which has an error  "Undefined index: id"
I am trying to add a visitor in prisoner id = 7

add_vistor.php

```
<?php include 'connect.php'
$idd =$_GET['id'];
if(isset($_POST['add-visitor'])){

    $id = $row['prisoner_id'];
    $visitorr = $_POST['name'];
    $datee = $_POST['date'];
    $timee = $_POST['time'];
    $aff = $_POST['aff'];
    $add = $_POST['hadd'];


    $result2 = $connect->query("INSERT INTO visitations (visitor,date_of_visit,time_of_visit,affinity,homeAddress) 
        VALUES ('$visitorr','$datee','$timee','$aff','$add') WHERE id = '$idd'") 
        or die($connect->error);

    header("Location: admin_view.php");
```

HTML

```
<form method = 'post' action = 'add_visitor.php' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="add.css">

     <input type = 'hidden' name = 'submitted' value = 'true'>
  <!-- POPUP BUTTON       -->             
    <div class="main">
        <div class="#">
            <a href="#login_form" id="login_pop" class = 'add'>Add</a>
        </div>
    </div>
  <!-- popup form -->
            <a class="overlay" id="login_form"></a>
               <div class="popup">
                 <h4>Add Visitor</h4>
               <div>
               <label>Name</label>
               <input type="text" name="name"/>
               </div>
               <div>
               <label>Date of Visit</label>
               <input type="date" name="date"/>
               </div>
               <div>
               <label>Time of Visit</label>
               <input type="time" name="time"/>
               </div>
               <div>
               <label>Affinity</label>
               <input type="text" name="aff"/>
               </div>
               <div>
               <label>Home Address</label>
               <input type="text" name="hadd"/>
               </div>


               <input type="submit" value="Add Visitor" name = "add" class = 'add'/>
               <?php echo "<a href ='admin_view.php?id=$id' class='close'></a>"; 
                    ?>
    </div>


        </form>
```

This is what my url looks like when I add record to prisoner id = 7, is it right?

http://localhost:8080/jailbsystem/admin2/admin_view.php?id=7#login_form

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On an insert you don't need a WHERE clause and the error you are getting is because you don't have a column named id in your visitations table. Change your insert query to

```
$result2 = $connect->query("INSERT INTO visitations 
(prisoner_id,
 visitor,
 date_of_visit,
 time_of_visit,
 affinity,
 homeAddress)
 VALUES 
 ($idd,
 $visitorr,
 '$datee',
 '$timee',
 '$aff',
 '$add')") or die($connect->error);
```

Comment: I got my insert query from my update query since I want to add visitor on a certain prisoner because for example, if a visitor visits a prisoner, I'll update the prisoner's profile and add the visitor details. What should be my query? prisoner_id is a fkey in my visitations table

Comment: My answer is the solution to your insert query. The visitations_id column in your visitations table should be an auto increment column so you don't have to include it in your insert or worry about it. There is nothing in what you posted that is updating the prisoner information and based on your description of what you are trying to do the prisoner information should not be touched when adding a visitation.